# What is the function of "&" right before the session variable?

Tags: php

`$cart = &$_SESSION['journal_items'];` anybody know when do we use the `&` symbol like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically it means that `$cart` won't get the value stored in `$_SESSION['journal_items']`, but it's reference. Whenever you call `$cart`, you'll be calling the current value of `$_SESSION['journal_items']`, even if it has been changed after this declaration.

Example:

```
$_SESSION['journal_items'] = "test";
$cart = &$_SESSION['journal_items'];
//$cart's current value is "test"

$_SESSION['journal_items'] = "test2";
//$cart's current value is "test2"
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2422913/4802649) and this [reference book](http://www.phpreferencebook.com/samples/php-pass-by-reference/).

Comment: Thanks for the help @phiter, really helpful